# Android Manifest File weird location Tags

Tags: applications, networking

I've started to read about the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and the `network_security_config.xml`.
So if I want to include the `network_security_config.xml` then I use this:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@path/to/config"
```

Yesterday I reversed a APK and inspected the `AndroidManifest.xml`.
The file-path to the `network_security_config.xml` is `/res/xml` so if I thinking right, the Path in the `AndroidManifest.xml` should look like this:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@res/xml/network_security_config"
```

instead I've found this:

```
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@7F140000"
```

What does this number mean and how is it build? Is this some sort of obfuscation? If not: for what is it used?

Kind regards,
Tyr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@res/xml/network_security_config` means that the file containing the network security configuration is included as file into the APK. If you open the APK file using a ZIP tool you will find the file in the path `/res/xml/network_security_config.xml`.

If you use a decompiler like Jadx you can open the item `/Resources/res/xml/network_security_config` to see the content of the `network_security_config.xml`.

The decompiled result `android:networkSecurityConfig="@7F140000"` should mean more or less the same, but the decompiler just shows the resourceID as it is saved in the AndroidManifest.xml file instead of resolving the resource name. You can use the automatically generated `R` class (the package name of the R class can be found in `AndroidManifest.xml` `<manifest package="..."`) for looking up the name of the resourceID (thanks to Andrew T. for pointing that out) . Depending on the used decompiler you may have to convert the resourceID from hexadecomal to decimal to find it.

Comment: For official reference: [Accessing your app resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#Accessing): "*When your application is compiled, `aapt` generates the `R` class, which contains resource IDs for all the resources in your `res/` directory. For each type of resource, there is an `R` subclass (for example, `R.drawable` for all drawable resources), and for each resource of that type, there is a static integer (for example, `R.drawable.icon`). **This integer is the resource ID that you can use to retrieve your resource.***"

Comment: Thank you both, now this gibberish is more clear!